# syntax error, unexpected 'compact' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to get all categories at create product page but it says:

> syntax error, unexpected 'compact' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

**Controller:**

```
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
      $categories = Category::distinct()->get();
      return view('admin.product.index' compact('categories'));
  }
```

**Blade:**

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
          <option selected="">Under Category</option>
          @foreach(categories as category)
             <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
       </select>
  </div>
```

**Error:** [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten a comma before `compact`:

```
return view('admin.product.index', compact('categories'));
```

And in your view you have forgotten `$` sign:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' (View: \\resources\views\admin\product\index.blade.php),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<select class="form-control" name="category_id">
   <?php $__currentLoopData = categories; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as category): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
      <option value="<?php echo e($category->id); ?>"><?php echo e($category->name); ?></option>
         <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                      </select>

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`$arr_view_data = [];
 $arr_view_data['categories'] = $categories;
 return view('admin.product.index',$arr_view_data);`

Answer (score 0):

Two errors I spot on your code, one inside controller and the other in the view. 
Perhaps you forgot to include comma in between, so it should be like

```
 return view('admin.product.index', compact('categories'));
```

While in the view, your looping is not correct, perhaps you miss the $ sign. It should be

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
```